# Как модифицировать код, чтобы он мог восприниматься Windows как служба?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, служба

Есть код на C++ (среда VS2008), который исполнительный файл себя ставит как служба с автозапуском. Запускаться как служба не хочет, но в списке служб появился. Нет ответа от самой программы, когда к ней обращается ОС, чтобы выяснить: ты служба или нет? Программа не знает что она служба! Как её научить? 
Windows выводит типа:

> Не удалось запустить службу Имя_моей_службы на Локальный компьютер 
>   Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.

Comment: Когда-то делал [так](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/ru).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, можно даже обычное Win-приложение запустить как сервис. Для этого есть множество утилит. Например, (какая неожиданность!) [runasservice](http://runasservice.com/)

В остальном все службы должны составляться по определенному шаблону. Посмотреть материалы по самостоятельному написанию служб предлагаю по следующим ссылкам:

1. [Создание своего Windows Service](http://habrahabr.ru/post/71533/);
2. [Пишем свой Windows service](http://habrahabr.ru/post/102826/);
3. [Шаблон "Служба Windows"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8dy6h580.aspx).